# Android sensor how to get the accuracy at anytime?

Tags: android, sensors, compass

I know the onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) callback, but it only happens when there's a change. How do I get the accuracy at anytime?

In Google Map, if you click on a POI where you're currently at, there's an option for you to Calibrate Compass, and in that screen they show you the current accuracy level.

In order words, after I calibrate my compass with figure 8, how do I check if my accuracy level indeed increases? I need a way something like sensor.getAccuracy() but I can't find that method.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that. You'll probably have to just listen to the onAccuracyChanged callback and keep track of that value yourself.

Comment: I thought of that. I have to keep track of it myself. But I'd like them to add something so I can just get it on init, or on the fly.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this at https://github.com/sky-map-team/stardroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/stardroid/activities/CompassCalibrationActivity.java

```
  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (!accuracyReceived) {
      onAccuracyChanged(event.sensor, event.accuracy);
    }
  }
```

Basically, it is calling the onAccuracyChanged() within onSensorChanged() at the initial stage to capture the current accuracy level at the beginning. Subsequently, onAccuracyChanged() will be called automatically by the system when there is a change to that. And, at anytime, you may also examine the value if event.accuracy in onSensorChanged() for any data received.